# How to write Testcafe selector('Withoutvalue').withText('Valid Text')?

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I am facing a scenario where the element tag name and attribute is changing from env to env, but the text content alone is unique.

Therefore I am not able to define any value for Selector('could not define anything here').

How could I write a path to locate the element ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a direct solution for this, but a workaround that could solve your issue. You could have an object that holds environments specific data for you and which helps you for specific cases as the one that you seem to be confronted with. In this object, you could also store environment specific Selectors. This could, written in TypeScript, look as follows:

```js
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

interface EnvironmentData {
  envName: string;
  myVariableSelector: Selector;
}

// Set up a list that contains environment specific data objects
const CONFIGS: EnvironmentData[] = [
  {
  envName: "MyEnv1",
  myVariableSelector: Selector("my css selector 1").withText("my text 1")
  },
  {
  envName: "MyEnv2",
  myVariableSelector: Selector("my css selector 2").withText("my text 2")
  },
  {
  envName: "MyEnv3",
  myVariableSelector: Selector("my css selector 3").withText("my text 3")
  }
]

// Assuming that you're CI for instance sets a environment variable ENVIRONMENT_NAME to 
// any of the specific environments MyEnv1, MyEnv2 or MyEnv3
function getConfigForEnvironment(envDataSets: EnvironmentData[]): EnvironmentData {
  const envData = envDataSets.find((c) => c.envName === process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME);

  if (envData === undefined) {
    console.error(`No suitable data for environment '${process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}' found!`);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  return envData;
}

// Determine the right object before the tests start
const envData = getConfigForEnvironment(CONFIGS);

fixture`My awesome tests`.page("myTestUrl");

test("My test", async (t) => {

// Make use of the object that holds the data for the desired environment
await t.expect(envData.myVariableSelector.exists).ok("Should be fine for any environment!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a simpler way using the or operator (,)

i,e I wrote the selector with Selector('div,span').withText('Value')

The attribute div and span are changing with environment so I used , to pass both and it worked.